# How can I exclude method visibility with annotations in Java?

Tags: java, annotations, dsl

For example, I have two different API for my simple DSL.

Old API:

```
client().userService().organization(«IBM»).user(«userId»).get();
```

And new API:

```
client().newAPI().userService().organization().user(user).get();
```

I want to exclude all methods from old API when I use trigger `newAPI()`. Methods of new API marked with annotation for example @NewAPI.

Is it possible to do something like this?

*PS*

Yes, I know it's hard to do this at compile time. But who knows meybe it's possible in Java.

Comment: Bit confused...where are u trigerring newAPI() method

Comment: What do you mean by "exclude all methods from old API"? Are you talking about code completion? Maybe you should start with the `@Deprecated` annotation?

Comment: Yes, maybe @Deprecated is a good solution. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

The method newAPI() could return a subset of the methods if the return type is only a sub-interface of the complete interface.

```
interface NewAPI {
  NewAPI organization();
  NewAPI user(User user);
  Result get();
}
interface ClientAPI extends NewAPI {
  @Deprecated
  ClientAPI organization(String s);
  @Deprecated
  ClientAPI user(String id);
  NewAPI newAPI();
}
```

The method `client()` would return an instance of `ClientAPI` and as soon as `newAPI()` was called, the deprecated methods are no longer available.